# Is there a "leader board" for bounties?

Tags: discussion

I just spent a little time looking at the [leader board](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/324/alltime/history/2011-10-11?sort=reputationchange&page=2) for History SE. Pretty fun to look at. Impressive as well.

Is there a way to see a snapshot of "all-time" leaders for bounties? a year-by-year comparison might be fun also. By "bounties", I mean a comparison of who has given the most.

Or is this something I will be able to see once I hit 5,000 points?

Answer (score 5):

I don't think there is a default report, but you could always create a query using the Stack Exchange [Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/).

I haven't got round to playing with this yet, but it looks like it has the potential to be a really useful and informative tool.  There are a large number of queries already in the system, so you could probably modify something to meet your needs.

---

### Top 100 Users by Bounties Received

The question [Unidentified best bounty hunter?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/221642/unidentified-best-bounty-hunter) on Meta:SE includes a query that I copied and ran on History:SE:

```
SELECT Top 100
  Posts.OwnerUserId As [User Link], COUNT(*) As BountiesWon
FROM Votes
  INNER JOIN Posts ON Votes.PostId = Posts.Id
WHERE
  VoteTypeId=9
GROUP BY
  Posts.OwnerUserId
ORDER BY
  BountiesWon DESC
```

---

This got the following results for an "*All-time Bounties Leaderboard*":

[image: Total bounties received by users]

---

Restricting the date may be a little more tricky.  I think I can restrict by the post creation date using something like:

```
WHERE
    votetypeid = 9 and creationdate between 'mm/dd/yyyy' AND 'mm/dd/yyyy'
```

(**remembering to use the US date format**), but, of course, a bounty could be awarded long after the actual post was created.

---

### Top 100 Users by Bounties Offered

The pre-existing query [Top 100 users ordered by offered bounties](https://data.stackexchange.com/history/query/1017638/top-100-users-ordered-by-offered-bounties) gets a list of the users who have offered the most bounties, and the total reputation offered in bounties:

[image: Users by bounties offered]

---

I added a line to restrict the search to a particular date range (in this case I set it to be 1 January 2018 - 31 December 2018):

```
SELECT TOP(100)
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY SUM(Votes.BountyAmount) DESC, Users.ID) AS rnSum
  ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC, Users.ID) AS rnCount
  ,Users.ID
  ,Users.DisplayName
  ,Users.Reputation
  ,SUM(Votes.BountyAmount) AS BountyOfferedTotal
  ,COUNT(*) AS BountyOfferedCount
FROM
  Votes
  INNER JOIN Posts ON Posts.ID = Votes.PostID
  INNER JOIN Users ON Users.ID = Posts.OwnerUserID
WHERE
  Votes.BountyAmount IS NOT NULL
  AND Votes.VoteTypeID = 8 -- BountyStart
  AND Posts.PostTypeID = 1 -- Question
  AND Votes.CreationDate between '01/01/2018' AND '12/31/2018'
GROUP BY
  Users.ID
  ,Users.DisplayName
  ,Users.Reputation
ORDER BY BountyOfferedTotal DESC, Users.ID
;
```

This got the following result:

[image: Bounties offered 2018]

Changing the date range and re-running the query would then get you your year-by-year comparison.

Comment: That appears to be bounties won, not bounties offered, but one would imagine if the former is possible, the latter is as well.

Comment: @T.E.D. Ah, yes. I misread the question.  I've updated to include bounties offered.  It's always good to actually answer the question that was asked!

Comment: ...a lesson I hope to one day learn myself.

Comment: Cool! So this data is already out there, and can be accessed by the link in your answer. Thanks! I wonder why mine shows "1 Bounty for 500" instead of "9 bounties for 1,000".

Answer (score 2):

I don't know the answer to the main thing you're asking. However, [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/160292/231379) goes over the reputation rewards. As we are an ungraduated site, it appears the only privilege you're lacking with 4K < rep < 5k is the ability to see the site analytics.

Comment: So at present, the question "Who gave the most bounties?" in 2018 is not answerable?